# How to add product rating on joomla module?

Tags: joomla

I created 1 module for joomla which shows product list with add to cart link and price of the product. I want to add product rating, product description and vote of that product.
Anybody knows how can I do this, I am new to joomla.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am using Joomla 1.5.23 version with virtuemart 1.1.8 version.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using virtuemart 2.0 (latest) with joomla , **navigate to** `components -> virtuemart ->  Products (tab) -> Reviews and ratings`

Comment: Thanks atif, I am using virtuemart 1.1.8 version in which there is no Reviews and ratings tab in components -> virtuemart -> Products(tab)